# Creating a single solution for multiple projects

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, nuget-package

I have 3 separate projects: an ASP.NET 5 MVC project and two ASP.NET 5 Class Library projects i.e. packaged projects.

These 3 projects all have their own solutions and they reference each other. For example, the MVC project references both class library projects -- thru NuGet packages.

They're set up separately because we want granular access to these projects through our repository.

I have access to all three projects and would like work with them in a single solution. What's the right way to set them up?

I assume I need to create a blank solution and import all three projects into that solution. My question is, how do I handle their references? Please keep in mind that the class library projects all produce NuGet packages.

Comment: Are they all in the same repository? What revision control solution are you using?

Comment: We're using VSTS -- aka VSO. They're in the same repository and we want to have very granular control over who has access to each project. There are however people like me who need access to all three projects so I'm trying to find an easy way to work on all three projects and be able to debug -- even make code changes when necessary.

Comment: Why do you need to access all 3? To me it sounds like it's one big project. You say it's not but you haven't provided any evidence otherwise

Comment: It is a big project but we do want to control access to each individual project. We don't want frontend developers downloading the whole application and vice versa. It's a security issue.

Comment: Then separate the projects and treat them as 3. It's really that simple

Comment: They are already separate projects. My issue is when I debug the code in MVC project which calls a function in one of the class library projects, I want to be able to step through the code wherever it may go. If necessary, make changes to the code and be able to check it in. When they're completely separate, I'm not able to step through the code.

Comment: Do you want to package your pdb files with your nuget packages? Probably not but I think that would accomplish your goal... albeit it really strange

Comment: I hear you. The more I think about this, the more I get convinced that this needs to be a single solution with multiple projects that directly reference each other. Thank you for trying to help. Happy new year!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options. None of which are what you're currently doing.

1. Keep them all as one solution and get rid of your old solutions. You can then use "project references"
2. Use git submodules
3. Build nuget packages for your class libraries and import those into your reliant projects

Comment: We do want to keep them separate though because the idea is to assign them to separate teams. So when MVC project team downloads the solution, they should be able to work on it independently. When a class library gets updated, the MVC team would simply update the NuGet package. I'm the first one who has access to all 3 projects. I don't want to do anything that would change the structure of these projects. On the other hand, I want to be able to work on them in a single solution so that I can debug them.

Answer (score 0):

> I assume I need to create a blank solution and import all three
>   projects into that solution. My question is, how do I handle their
>   references?

Right, create a blank solution and import all projects in that.

Then, for each project, can you not put all references in a shared location, so that every time a package reference is updated in any of the class libraries, your packaged solution have the updated references as well? (hopefully I am understanding your situation right).

HNY

Answer (score 0):

If I don't miss anything this should work for you

Create your blank *all-in-one solution* as you suggested.

*Why not* create a `global.json` file in that *all-in-one solution* and set it's `projects` field to target your 3 project's folder?

Like:

```
{
  "projects": [
    "../MVC-Solution/src",
    "../Class-Library-1/src",
    "../Class-Library-2/src"
  ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  }
}
```

This way your MVC project will use the class libraries as local development nuget packages and you will be able to debug into them without any extra effort.
And the projects still will remain seperated.

When you add that information into `global.json` file, `dnu` looks into those folders for the `project.json` projects. No matter where they are or who uses them...

> I assume I need to create a blank solution and import all three projects into that solution. My question is, how do I handle their references?

-

> They are already separate projects. My issue is when I debug the code in MVC project which calls a function in one of the class library projects, I want to be able to step through the code wherever it may go. If necessary, make changes to the code and be able to check it in. When they're completely separate, I'm not able to step through the code.